# Проблема связывания Id и данных на фронтенде

Tags: javascript, архитектура

Описываю банальнейшую вещь, на фронтенд приходят данные и эти данные нужно по особому обработать в зависимости от типа. Например, у нас есть список с животными, нужно его отрисовать и если это котик - добавить картинку с клубком.
Пример модели:

```
var model= {
"animals" = [{Id = 1, name ="Murzik", typeId = 1}, {Id = 2, name ="Snezok", typeId = 1}, {Id = 3, name ="Barbos", typeId = 2}],
"animalTypes = [{typeId = 1, name="Cat"},{typeId = 2, name="Dog"},{typeId = 3, name="Fish"}]
}
```

Хардкод типа `if(typeId = 1)` ,наверное, не вариант. Но мне кажется, что без хардкода в том или ином виде тут не обойтись без чрезмерного усложнения. 
Какие бестпрактис для таких простых случаев в мире современного веб девелопинга?

Comment: Я бы предложил переделать **anymalTypes** в хеш таблицу. Тогда все typeID станут ключами своих объектов (_{1: {name: "Cat"}, ...}_). Таким образом можно будет воспользоваться простейшим map'ом и назначать доп. атрибуты - картинки, например.

Comment: @Mr. Brightside дмую стоит оформить это в виде ответа.

Comment: @Arnial сделано

Answer (score 2):

anymalTypes можно переделать в хеш таблицу.

Тогда все typeID станут ключами своих объектов и выглядеть это будет как то так:

```
{
  1: {name: "Cat"},
  2: {name: "Dog"}
}
```

Таким образом можно будет воспользоваться простейшим map'ом и назначать доп. атрибуты - картинки, например.

Ситуация еще более упростится, если полученная хеш-таблица будет содержать ссылки на картинки:

```
{
  1: {name: "Cat", image: '/remoteFolder/catImage.png'},
  2: {name: "Dog", image: '/remoteFolder/dogImage.png'}
}
```

Тогда для получения, например, изображения для Murzik'a можно будет использовать:

```
animalTypes[animal[0].typeId].image
```

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно просто взять статичное значение, соответсвующее типу, то подходит и хэш таблица, и можно прямо вписать значения:

```
var model= {
  "animals": [{Id:1, name:"Murzik", typeId:1}, {Id:2, name:"Snezok", typeId:1}, {Id:3, name:"Barbos", typeId:2}],
  "animalTypes": [{typeId:1, name:"Cat"},{typeId:2, name:"Dog"},{typeId:3, name:"Fish"}]
};
var types = {};
model.animalTypes.forEach(e => { types[e.typeId] = e.name; });
model.animals.forEach( e => { e.type = types[e.typeId] });

/* JSON.stringify( model.animals )
[{"Id":1,"name":"Murzik","typeId":1,"type":"Cat"},{"Id":2,"name":"Snezok","typeId":1,"type":"Cat"},{"Id":3,"name":"Barbos","typeId":2,"type":"Dog"}]
*/
```

Если же речь именно про действия в зависимости от типа, то надо действие обернуть в функцию или метод, и вызывать соответствующий. Например, назовем методы так же, как тип – `Cat()`, `Dog()`. Тогда допишем к коду выше:

```
function Cat() { /* рисуем клубок */ }
function Dog() { /* косточку */ }
function Fish() { /* червячка */ }

model.animals.forEach( e => {
  if( this[ e.type]) this[ e.type](); // вызов ф-ии, если такая есть
});
```